# Array separation by checking entire array

Tags: php, codeigniter

- Below is the sample array in which [a] and [b] key in entire array is having value 'aa', again [a] and [b] key is having value 'bb' .
- If these are matching it should be made separated like below. This should happen dynamically.

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => aa  //this is matching with 3rd array with b key
            [b] => bb

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => bb
            [b] => cc
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => cc
            [b] => bb
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [a] => bb
            [b] => aa  //this is matching with 0th array with a key
        )

)
```

---

**Below is the output i want**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => aa  
            [b] => bb

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => bb
            [b] => cc
        )
)
```

---

```
Array
(

    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => cc
            [b] => bb
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [a] => bb
            [b] => aa
        )

)
```

---

This is how i tried, Below is not the correct way even though i am pasting my code.

```
$array_count = count($onw_return); // $onw_return is the complete array
$jk = count($onw_return)-1; 
for($jj=0;$jj<$array_count;$jj++)
{
if( in_array($onw_return[$jj]['sour'],$onw_return)){
echo "aa"; //this should come 2 times
}else{
echo  "bb";//this should come 2 times
}
$jk--;
}
```

Comment: i tried by using in_array(), but not get it, please help me how to solve this dynamically.

Comment: Apply your code first. Try to solve it on your own first.

Comment: i pasted my code sample,check it out !!!!!!